# Efficiently Assigning a common ID to Related Rows in Large DataFrame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am working with a large dataset in R, consisting of approximately 19 million rows, and over 81 columns, I need some guidance on efficiently processing it.

My dataset tracks reoccuring records by name (actually another ID but for simplicity let's say name here), alongside their value, start, and end dates, with some records having been cancelled after a few years. Here is a simplified example of my data structure:

| name | value | cancelled | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 77 |  | 2010 | 2011 |
| ABC | 66 |  | 2010 | 2011 |
| ABC | 55 |  | 2010 | 2011 |
| ABC | 44 |  | 2011 | 2012 |
| ABC | 33 | 2012 | 2011 | 2012 |
| ABC | 22 |  | 2011 | 2012 |
| ABC | 11 |  | 2012 | 2013 |
| ABC | 44 |  | 2012 | 2013 |
| BAA | 33 |  | 2009 | 2012 |
| BAA | 22 |  | 2009 | 2010 |
| BAA | 45 |  | 2009 | 2010 |
| BAA | 23 | 2011 | 2009 | 2011 |
| BAA | 54 |  | 2010 | 2011 |
| BAA | 15 |  | 2012 | 2013 |
| BAA | 42 |  | 2010 | 2011 |

My goal is to assign a unique ID to each sequence of related record, where a sequence is defined by consecutive record sharing the same name. My basic understanding is, if row has no cancellation date, then match row 1 of name ABC, to the next occuring row 2 of ABC, where the end date of a row 1 matches the start date of row 2. If a record is cancelled, it should not be linked to subsequent occurrences of the same name. For instance, the **desired outcome would look like this** (new unique id created for association, that allows me to first sort by name, then by unique id, then by start date):

| name | value | cancelled | start | end | new_unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 77 |  | 2010 | 2011 | 1 |
| ABC | 44 |  | 2011 | 2012 | 1 |
| ABC | 11 |  | 2012 | 2013 | 1 |
| ABC | 66 |  | 2010 | 2011 | 2 |
| ABC | 33 | 2012 | 2011 | 2012 | 2 |
| ABC | 55 |  | 2010 | 2011 | 3 |
| ABC | 22 |  | 2011 | 2012 | 3 |
| ABC | 44 |  | 2012 | 2013 | 3 |
| BAA | 33 |  | 2009 | 2012 | 4 |
| BAA | 15 |  | 2012 | 2013 | 4 |
| BAA | 22 |  | 2009 | 2010 | 5 |
| BAA | 54 |  | 2010 | 2011 | 5 |
| BAA | 45 |  | 2009 | 2010 | 6 |
| BAA | 42 |  | 2010 | 2011 | 6 |
| BAA | 23 | 2011 | 2009 | 2011 | 7 |

Given the scale of my dataset (3GB FST & 17 Mio & 81 columns), using a traditional loop in R is proving to be inefficient. I am looking for a way to leverage vectorized operations or dplyr (or any other you can think of) functions to accomplish this task more efficiently.

Any insights or suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated!

edit: adding the r tables for
table 1 (before):

```
table_before <- data.frame(
  name = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA"),
  value = c(77, 66, 55, 44, 33, 22, 11, 44, 33, 22, 45, 23, 54, 15, 42),
  cancelled = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2012, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2011, NA, NA, NA),
  start = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2012, 2010),
  end = c(2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2012, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2013, 2011)
)

# The following is a desired state that I wish to achieve, as you can see the rows are sorted first by "Name", then by a unique id that should be generated and groups the rows together (associates them)

table_after <- data.frame(
  name = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA"),
  value = c(77, 44, 11, 66, 33, 55, 22, 44, 33, 15, 22, 54, 45, 42, 23),
  cancelled = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2012, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2011),
  start = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2009, 2012, 2009, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2009),
  end = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2011, 2012, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2010, 2011, 2011),
  new_unique_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7)
)
```

edit: I have simplified the dataframe by first sorting by name, then by year and removed shortened by two rows which may made it unnecessarily complicated.

edit: here is a depiction of the first-come-first-serve logic. Simply put: For each row, check if a unique ID exists and if not, assign new id and find subsequent matches based on first find.
[image]

edit: another depiction of the issue
[image]

Comment: Thank you @LulY, I cross-checked the r tables, what order is wrong here? Your help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: In the table the start column is 2010, 2011, ... but in the table_before the start column is 2010, 2010, ... Data is not in same order. For table_before it is unclear how to define new id.

Comment: How do you define *consecutive record*. If start[i] <= end[i-1] then consecutive?

Comment: I missed the fact that your `start`/`end` values are repeating in `table_before`. How _exactly_ are we safe to assume that when they are the same, we should _increase_ the data values? That seems arbitrary and/or creating data to fill what we want.

Comment: I think some of the confusion is that `table_before` is arranged by `name` and `start`, but `table_after` has been re-arranged by `new_unique_id`.

Comment: @zephryl thank you, that's what I was missing. Having learned that, I think that this is an optimization problem (bin-packing), where you are trying to find the longest sequence (before cancelling) of possibly-consecutive rows, and then find the second-longest, etc. Why is it, for instance, that the `77` row of `2010-2011` is assigned `new_unique_id` when it could also have been `66` or `55`?

Comment: @r2evans thank you! The value 77 row was asssigned the "1" id as it was the first ever mention of a name&startyear&endyear combination, once this combination reoccurs, see row with value 66 it receives the "2" id, as it is the second mention of the same name&startyear&endyear combination. Afterwards the first mention of name&previousendyear&currentendyear is used to find the subsequent row.

Comment: @Botan, since this is a bit more complicated, the fact that you have 19 million rows complicates the process. It cannot be vectorized unless you can give more insight into how to know which `start=2011` should come after which `end=1011` (since there are multiples). Even if it is 1-to-1, unless there is a deterministic way to arrange them beforehand, it seems any solution is going to be slow

Comment: @r2evans I understand and you are absolutely right. The subsequent start is always the previous end, now as you say there are many of these combinations. This might help. For instance, row one has end=2011 and now I need to find the next row where start=2011 (as there are many, I pick the very first I find and assign it the same unique_id). Now that this row too has a unique ID it cannot be assigned to unique_id=2, which may have all the same name&start&end combinations in its first mention. I will create a visualization to help.

Comment: @r2evans I have added an image depicting the logic. To clarify, the second table is sorted by name, id, and lastly year. I thought it might increase understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain this will scale *awesomely*, but we can use this function to align/arrange rows.

```r
fun <- function(start, end, cnx) {
  group <- replace(rep(NA, length(start)), start == min(start),
                   seq_len(sum(start == min(start))))
  start0 <- start
  for (rn in seq_along(start0)) {
    ind <- which(start0 %in% end[rn] & !cnx[rn])
    if (length(ind)) {
      group[ind[1]] <- group[rn]
      start0[ind[1]] <- NA
    }
  }
  group
}
```

One caveat is that since this finds the *first* (of possibly many) match, it is not exactly the groupings that you have in your data.

## dplyr

Using `dplyr_1.1.0`; if you have an older version, replace all `.by=c(..)` with a corresponding before `group_by(..)` before the respective dplyr-verb.

```r
library(dplyr)
tmp <- table_before |>
  mutate(.by = name, unique_id = fun(start, end, !is.na(cancelled))) |>
  arrange(name, unique_id, start)
tmp |>
  summarize(.by = name, prevmax = max(unique_id)) |>
  mutate(prevmax = c(0, cumsum(prevmax)[-n()])) |>
  right_join(tmp, by = "name") |>
  mutate(unique_id = unique_id + prevmax) |>
  select(-prevmax)
#    name value cancelled start  end unique_id
# 1   ABC    77        NA  2010 2011         1
# 2   ABC    44        NA  2011 2012         1
# 3   ABC    11        NA  2012 2013         1
# 4   ABC    16        NA  2013 2014         1
# 5   ABC    66        NA  2010 2011         2
# 6   ABC    33      2012  2011 2012         2
# 7   ABC    55        NA  2010 2011         3
# 8   ABC    22        NA  2011 2012         3
# 9   ABC    44        NA  2012 2013         3
# 10  ABC    10        NA  2013 2014         3
# 11  BAA    33        NA  2009 2012         4
# 12  BAA    15        NA  2012 2013         4
# 13  BAA    22        NA  2009 2010         5
# 14  BAA    54        NA  2010 2011         5
# 15  BAA    45        NA  2009 2010         6
# 16  BAA    42        NA  2010 2011         6
# 17  BAA    23      2011  2009 2011         7
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(table_before)[, unique_id := fun(start, end, !is.na(cancelled)), by = "name"] |>
  setorder(name, unique_id, start)
DT[, .(prevmax = max(unique_id)), by = "name"
  ][, prevmax := c(0, cumsum(prevmax)[-.N])
  ][DT, on = "name"
  ][, unique_id := unique_id + prevmax]
#       name prevmax value cancelled start   end unique_id
#     <char>   <num> <num>     <num> <num> <num>     <num>
#  1:    ABC       0    77        NA  2010  2011         1
#  2:    ABC       0    44        NA  2011  2012         1
#  3:    ABC       0    11        NA  2012  2013         1
#  4:    ABC       0    16        NA  2013  2014         1
#  5:    ABC       0    66        NA  2010  2011         2
#  6:    ABC       0    33      2012  2011  2012         2
#  7:    ABC       0    55        NA  2010  2011         3
#  8:    ABC       0    22        NA  2011  2012         3
#  9:    ABC       0    44        NA  2012  2013         3
# 10:    ABC       0    10        NA  2013  2014         3
# 11:    BAA       3    33        NA  2009  2012         4
# 12:    BAA       3    15        NA  2012  2013         4
# 13:    BAA       3    22        NA  2009  2010         5
# 14:    BAA       3    54        NA  2010  2011         5
# 15:    BAA       3    45        NA  2009  2010         6
# 16:    BAA       3    42        NA  2010  2011         6
# 17:    BAA       3    23      2011  2009  2011         7
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! But table_after is an example depiction of my desired output table, I do not have table_after presently. The goal is to go from table_before to table_after using R. Is there a way to solve this still?

Comment: See my edit @Botan, I think it might perform well-enough with 19Mi rows (though definitely not _awesome_)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
df$semi_id <- c(FALSE,
                df$start[2:(nrow(df))] < df$start[1:(nrow(df)-1)] |
                  df$name[2:(nrow(df))] != df$name[1:(nrow(df)-1)])
df$new_unique_id <- 1+ cumsum(df$semi_id)

> df
   name cancelled start semi_id new_unique_id
1   ABC        NA  2010   FALSE             1
2   ABC        NA  2011   FALSE             1
3   ABC        NA  2012   FALSE             1
4   ABC        NA  2013   FALSE             1
5   ABC        NA  2010    TRUE             2
6   ABC      2012  2011   FALSE             2
7   ABC        NA  2010    TRUE             3
8   ABC        NA  2011   FALSE             3
9   ABC        NA  2012   FALSE             3
10  ABC        NA  2013   FALSE             3
11  BAA        NA  2009    TRUE             4
12  BAA        NA  2012   FALSE             4
13  BAA        NA  2009    TRUE             5
14  BAA        NA  2010   FALSE             5
15  BAA        NA  2009    TRUE             6
16  BAA        NA  2010   FALSE             6
17  BAA      2011  2009    TRUE             7
```

What this does: `df$start[2:(nrow(df))] < df$start[1:(nrow(df)-1)]` looks whether a date was earlier than the date in the row before and `df$name[2:(nrow(df))] != df$name[1:(nrow(df)-1)]` looks whether the name is not the same as in the row before. If one of both is the case, a `TRUE` is returned. Later you simply add the number of `TRUE`s with `cumsum()` which gives you the new id column.

Make sure that the data is the correct order as in your question. The data you provided later with `table_before` is in another row order. In the table of the question  the `start` column is `2010, 2011, ...` but in the `table_before` `start` column is `2010, 2010, ...`. The data is not in same order. My answer refers to the visible table you provided. For `table_before` it is unclear how to define new id.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but this does not work. I have also cross-checked the order over and over but the R code I inserted appears to be correct. Printing the before table results in the same table as the questions visual table. I used your code on that table but did not achieve your output :-/ there are only 1,...,4 unique IDs and start/end is not sorted either.

Comment: @Botan Double check again because `table_before` is not correct.

Comment: @Botan The second entry in the `start` column of the table is `2011` but in the `table_before` the second entry is `2010`, for example.

Comment: @LulY to clarify, the second table is the desired table, I wish that the code I have genertes a unique_id that I can use for grouping/sorting. I currently only have table_before and solely created table_after for a desired output state. The code for table_before refers to the first visual table, the table_after refers to the second visual table. I hope this helps clarify the issue. I do not have the second table, it is my desired goal to have such structure in place that allows me to have a unique id for sorting purposes. Please let me know if I misunderstood, very sorry!